Не импортируется Code128 из barcode
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_file, session, flash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import mm
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
import qrcode
import sqlite3
from functools import wraps

Ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 384, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 88, in load_app
    spec.loader.exec_module(app_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/users/j/j94546558/domains/e6c1658f1eda.hosting.myjino.ru/passenger_wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    from main import main as application  # Замените 'app' на имя вашего файла приложения
  File "/home/users/j/j94546558/domains/e6c1658f1eda.hosting.myjino.ru/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from barcode import Code128
ImportError: cannot import name 'Code128' from 'barcode' (/home/users/j/j94546558/domains/e6c1658f1eda.hosting.myjino.ru/.venv/python310/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/barcode/__init__.py)

на хостинге почему то отказывается импортировать а на пк все норм

Проверьте, что версия barcode одна и та же установлена (и вообще, что один и тот же пакет установлен)

Из документации https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/supported-formats.html#code-128: "Code 128. New in version 0.8beta1." Видимо, на хостинге стоит версия старее чем вот эта 0.8beta1.
